# How do I call a method that's in one Ruby script from another?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
module CommonMethods  

  def createLog()  
     $log = Logger.new(logPath)  
     puts "Doesn't seem to fire..."  
     $log.level=Logger::INFO  
     return $log  
  end
```

in shared.rb.

I'm attempting to call it from another script, but eventually need to call it from multiple scripts, like this:

```
require_relative "shared"
include CommonMethods
CommonMethods.createLog
```

but, it doesn't seem to be actually doing anything.

I tried creating `$log` as a local variable, and as a global variable, but not "return"ing it.  I tried everything I can think of (I'm coming from a C# background) and I can't get it right.

In this example, I'm trying to make a call to an external method to create "log", which I can then utilize locally.  I'm going to be doing the same with many other methods, but not until I can get the method call correct.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please remove subjective and/or personal expressions from the title and the text.

Comment: If you're referring to my puts, I was testing without that for a long while.  I added it when I thought things weren't firing, and sho nuff, they weren't.

Comment: What result are you actually seeing? An error, or just no output? Although there are several things that need fixing or explaining, the code you have should actually work (as long as `logPath` is defined somewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are built for organizing methods and will be happy to be included. If you included a module, you no longer need the namespace.

```
require_relative "shared"
include CommonMethods
createLog # Call it simply
```

Comment: Pretend I'm dumb (some days more so than others) and show me the other half of the code that would make this work.  I tried with "Module" earlier, and that's what sparked the initial query.  I switched "Module" for "Class" in the defining script, and now it's working (thanks to your comment above re "self"), but if I try to include the class, it tells me it's the wrong argument type (expected).  If I wanted to do as a module, do I need to do a class, then add the module within the class to make it work this way?

Comment: @mikecole79, Class is to be initiated, but not included. like `foo = Foo.new`, you can also call class method like screenmutt mentioned above. Module can be included as in my answer, and the methods can be called directly with `self` as well. Also I don't understand why you use `$` in your variable, which is global variable that rarely used. I suggest you stop working for a while and read some basic book at first :)

Comment: Not a bad suggestion in the least.  The global variable was because I was having issues passing control back and forth and wanted to see if it was a scope issue or some other funky force at work.  I have a couple of books picked out that I'm working my way through for this project as well.  Thank you all for the help with this issue.  I suspect after getting some sleep (hopefully this weekend) and a chance to read a bit more things will start coming a little more into focus.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby modules must be included inside of a class. See [the documentation for Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html).

What you most likely want is a class.

common_methods.rb:

```
class CommonMethods  
  def self.createLog()  
     $log = Logger.new(logPath)  
     puts "Doesn't seem to fire..."  
     $log.level=Logger::INFO  
     return $log  
  end  
end
```

And in other file:

```
require 'common_methods'
CommonMethods.createLog
```

Comment: Followed your instructions.  Still doesn't want to give me anything.  I added a new method to the class called testThis(), and when I try to fire that or the original method from the other script I'm returned a "undefined method" error.

Comment: If you call `CommonMethods.createLog`, the method must be a class method instead of an instance one. `def self.createlog`. And there is no need of brace.

Comment: Right on both accounts.

Comment: @BillyChan you just prevented my head from exploding today.  Thank you.  That's the addition I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to call `createLog` like it's a class method, when in fact it isn't. If you want to call `CommonMethods.createLog`, you'll have to make `createLog` a class method by defining it like this:

```
module CommonMethods
  def self.createLog() # Note that it's self.createLog
    $log = Logger.new(logPath)
    puts "Doesn't seem to fire..."
    $log.level=Logger::INFO
    return $log
  end
end
```

Then you call it like this:

```
require 'common_methods'
CommonMethods.createLog
```

---

If, however, you want to `include` the module in a class (which is what modules are generally meant to be used for) you'll have to leave createLog as an "instance method", and then include the module.

```
module CommonMethods
  def createLog()
    $log = Logger.new(logPath)
    puts "Doesn't seem to fire..."
    $log.level=Logger::INFO
    return $log
  end
end
```

Then you use it like this:

```
require 'common_methods'

class SomeOtherClass
  include CommonMethods # Include methods from CommonMethods
end

foo = SomeOtherClass.new
foo.createLog # createLog is an instance method on 'foo' now
```